# Code is compiling but won't print using command line prompt

Tags: c, command-line, command-line-arguments

I really have no clue why this won't compile. Some feedback would be appreciated. If possible, I would just like small hint or a point in the right direction instead of giving me the answer. Thanks much, folks.

The purpose of this code is as follows:

- ./a.out   R  S

  - R is the number of rolls
  - S is the seed for srand
  - if not supplied, R is 30   S is 13
  - can supple R&S, R, none
- roll 2 dice; frequency of the sum of 2 values
- use 11 sided dice
- output should be well formatted & informative

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, int argv[] )
{
    int dice1, dice2, sum;
    int R, S, k, g, j, x, count = 0;
    int list[22];
    int nums[22] = {0};

    for( j = 2; j < 23; j++ )
    {
        list[j] = j;
    }

    if( argc != 3 )
    {
        R = 30;
        S = 13;
    }
    else
    {
        R = argv[1];
        S = argv[2];
    }

    srand( S );

    for( k = R; k > 0; k-- )
    {
        dice1 = rand() % 11 + 1;
        dice2 = rand() % 11 + 1;

        sum = (dice1 + dice2);
        for( g = 2; g < 23; g )
        {
            if( sum == list[g] )
            {
                nums[count] += 1;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    count = 0;

    for( x = 2; x < 23; x++ )
    {
        printf("Frequency of %d: %d\n", x, nums[count]);
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First observation: `for( j = 2; j < 23; j++ )` will index `list[j]` out of bounds, defined as `int list[22];`

Comment: My apologies, I used some unsaved code that I sent to a friend to see if he could assist me. THIS should be the updated code that I'm currently working with.

Comment: Second: `int R = argv[1];` is the wrong type because `argv[1]` has type `char *`. C has no automatic conversion from string types to integers.

Comment: I initialized argv[] as an int, so shouldn't that work? @Weather Vane

Comment: The `R` and `S` you supplied as program arguments are always *strings*. Even if you typed numbers, they still arrive as strings, not integers. I suggest `R = atoi(argv[1]); S = atoi(argv[2]);`

Comment: No. It will treat the provided char * [] as an int [], with results that you probably don't want.

Comment: Alright, I've fixed the issue with my list[] going out of bounds, and I've tested it with a printf() to make sure it works. So, despite my using "int argv[]", the code still uses "char *argv[]"? @Weather Vane

Comment: No, mis-using the standard arguments for `main` does not automatically change them to what you want. It should be `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` That's an array of pointers to strings - the ones you supplied.

Comment: Alright, I've changed the int main() to the proper argument and I've attempted the use of atoi(), but I'm still receiving no output from my print statement. @Weather Vane

Comment: What does "no output" mean? I suggest you make a simple test program to explore how the program arguments work, and nothing else.

Comment: When I say "no output", I mean my print statement at the bottom is not printing anything at all. @Weather Vane

Comment: That is impossible.

Comment: I'm typing "./a.out" and nothing is printing at all. I've even tried adding 2 integers to fill in the argument slots and nothing is happening. I'm not sure what to do. @Weather Vane

Comment: does it just hang and you have to Ctrl+c to quit?

Comment: That's exactly what happens. @yano

Comment: `for( g = 2; g < 23; g )` This is an infinite loop, `g` never changes. You probably meant `for( g = 2; g < 23; g++ )`

Comment: Good catch, I thougth OP means the program *ends* without printing anything.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what the problem was. It's printing now, but I'm under the impression it's not right. I'll just have to debug it. Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it yourself. It's more than basic. Check the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) // argc is number of arguments, argv[][] is list of arguments that are strings
{
    int dice1, dice2, sum;
    int R, S, k, g, j, x, count = 0;
    int list[23]; // increase size of these arrays as you will go out of bounds
    int nums[23] = {0};

    for( j = 2; j < 23; j++ ) // j==22 is out of bounds, if you need j==22, increase `list' and `nums' size (above)
    {
        list[j] = j;
    }

    if( argc != 3 )
    {
        R = 30;
        S = 13;
    }
    else
    {
        R = atoi(argv[1]); // convert string to int
        S = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    srand( S );

    for( k = R; k > 0; k-- )
    {
        dice1 = rand() % 11 + 1;
        dice2 = rand() % 11 + 1;

        sum = (dice1 + dice2);
        for( g = 2; g < 22; g++ ) // do something with g, like increment for example, as it's infinite loop
        {
            if( sum == list[g] )
            {
                nums[count] += 1;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    count = 0;

    for( x = 2; x < 23; x++ )
    {
        printf("Frequency of %d: %d\n", x, nums[count]);
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Here is a diff](https://pastebin.com/MEQdFs15) that will hopefully help you to see the difference. You can get it yourself with `$ diff -rup rst1.c rst2.c > rst2.diff`.

PS. I think all things had been pointed in the comments so you should give thumb up to everyone of them.